# Duplicate entry in attach pivot table laravel

Tags: laravel

I got this error

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2-7-8' for key 'cart_product_cart_id_product_id_price_id_unique' (SQL: insert into `cart_product` (`cart_id`, `created_at`, `price_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`, `updated_at`) values (2, 2023-01-09 12:23:57, 8, 7, 1, 2023-01-09 12:23:57))"
```

Code:

```
$cart_product = $cart->products()
    ->where('product_id', $product->id)
    ->where('price_id', $price->id)
    ->first();

if ($cart_product->structure == 'single') {
    $cart->products()->attach(array([
        'product_id' => $product->id,
        'quantity'   => $request->quantity,
        'price_id'   => $price->id
    ]));
}
```

How can add a row to table product_cart although it already exists ?

Comment: If the entry already exists, why would you want to add another?

Comment: Is about structure of add product to cart

Answer (score 0):

You can do,  if it exists, Update. If not, Add. (*Basic concept of update or create*)

```
if ($cart_product->structure == 'single') {
    if ($cart->products()->where('product_id', $product->id)->where('price_id', $price->id)->exists()) {
        // Update
        $cart->products()->updateExistingPivot($product->id, [
            'quantity' => $request->quantity,
            'price_id' => $price->id
        ]);
    } else {
        // Insert
        $cart->products()->attach(array([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'quantity'   => $request->quantity,
            'price_id'   => $price->id
        ]));
    }
}
```

Comment: I just need if the structure of the product is single create a new record on pivot table

Comment: your code update row of table

Answer (score 0):

if you need to duplicated data cause you need to update one element

you can use `sync()` method like :-

```
$cart->products()->sync(array([
                'product_id' => $product->id,
                'quantity'   => $request->quantity,
                'price_id'   => $price->id
            ]));
```

`sync()` mean if exit will update it, or will be create new record

Comment: I try your code but not create a new record, update a record

Comment: you can try `$cart->products()->syncWithPivotValues([$myValue])` instead of `sync()`
if not work you can try condition if object is empty `$cart->products()->attach()` for create new one